# Cannot install JuliaSymbolics / SymbolicUtils.jl

Tags: julia

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-100-generic x86_64), julia v1.7.
] add SymbolicUtils failed to install this package.
The output of `Pkg.precompile()` is:

```
Precompiling project...
✗ Groebner
✗ Symbolics
0 dependencies successfully precompiled in 8 seconds (327 already precompiled)

ERROR: The following 2 direct dependencies failed to precompile:

SymbolicUtils [d1185830-fcd6-423d-90d6-eec64667417b]

Error: Missing source file for SymbolicUtils [d1185830-fcd6-423d-90d6-eec64667417b]
Symbolics [0c5d862f-8b57-4792-8d23-62f2024744c7]

Failed to precompile Symbolics [0c5d862f-8b57-4792-8d23-62f2024744c7] to ~/.julia/compiled/v1.7/Symbolics/jl_VPYpQf.
ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: Package SymbolicUtils [d1185830-fcd6-423d-90d6-eec64667417b] is required but does     not seem to be installed:
 - Run `Pkg.instantiate()` to install all recorded dependencies.

Stacktrace:
 [1] _require(pkg::Base.PkgId)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:1089
 [2] require(uuidkey::Base.PkgId)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:1013
 [3] require(into::Module, mod::Symbol)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:997
 [4] include
   @ ./Base.jl:418 [inlined]
 [5] include_package_for_output(pkg::Base.PkgId, input::String, depot_path::Vector{String}, dl_load_path::Vector{String},     load_path::Vector{String}, concrete_deps::Vector{Pair{Base.PkgId, UInt64}}, source::Nothing)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:1318
 [6] top-level scope
   @ none:1
 [7] eval
   @ ./boot.jl:373 [inlined]
 [8] eval(x::Expr)
   @ Base.MainInclude ./client.jl:453
 [9] top-level scope
   @ none:1
in expression starting at ~/.julia/packages/Symbolics/kG5bl/src/Symbolics.jl:1

Stacktrace:
 [1] pkgerror(msg::String)
   @ Pkg.Types ~/software/julia-1.7.3/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Pkg/src/Types.jl:68
 [2] precompile(ctx::Pkg.Types.Context; internal_call::Bool, strict::Bool, warn_loaded::Bool, already_instantiated::Bool, kwargs::Base.Pairs{Symbol, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}})
   @ Pkg.API ~/software/julia-1.7.3/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Pkg/src/API.jl:1362
 [3] precompile
   @ ~/software/julia-1.7.3/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Pkg/src/API.jl:1013 [inlined]
 [4] #precompile#220
   @ ~/software/julia-1.7.3/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Pkg/src/API.jl:1011 [inlined]
 [5] precompile()
   @ Pkg.API ~/software/julia-1.7.3/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Pkg/src/API.jl:1011
 [6] top-level scope
   @ REPL[1]:1
```

Why can't I install it? I'm happy to provide more info if needed.

---

If I remove them by `Pkg.rm("SymbolicUtils"); Pkg.rm("Symbolics")`, `Pkg.precomile()` does work. Then `] add SymbolicUtils` yields:

```
   Resolving package versions...2.3
    Updating `~/.julia/environments/v1.7/Project.toml`
  [d1185830] + SymbolicUtils v0.19.11
    Updating `~/.julia/environments/v1.7/Manifest.toml`
  [1520ce14] + AbstractTrees v0.4.2
  [dce04be8] + ArgCheck v2.3.0
  [15f4f7f2] + AutoHashEquals v0.2.0
  [198e06fe] + BangBang v0.3.36
  [9718e550] + Baselet v0.1.1
  [e2ed5e7c] + Bijections v0.1.4
  [861a8166] + Combinatorics v1.0.2
  [a33af91c] + CompositionsBase v0.1.1
  [244e2a9f] + DefineSingletons v0.1.2
  [7c1d4256] + DynamicPolynomials v0.4.5
  [22cec73e] + InitialValues v0.3.1
  [2ee39098] + LabelledArrays v1.11.1
  [e9d8d322] + Metatheory v1.3.4
  [128add7d] + MicroCollections v0.1.2
  [102ac46a] + MultivariatePolynomials v0.4.6
  [42d2dcc6] + Referenceables v0.1.2
  [171d559e] + SplittablesBase v0.1.14
  [d1185830] + SymbolicUtils v0.19.11
  [8ea1fca8] + TermInterface v0.2.3
  [ac1d9e8a] + ThreadsX v0.1.10
  [28d57a85] + Transducers v0.4.73
  0 dependencies successfully precompiled in 2 seconds (319 already precompiled)
  1 dependency errored. To see a full report either run `import Pkg; Pkg.precompile()` or load the package
```

precompile yields:

````
ERROR: The following 1 direct dependency failed to precompile:

SymbolicUtils [d1185830-fcd6-423d-90d6-eec64667417b]

Error: Missing source file for SymbolicUtils [d1185830-fcd6-423d-90d6-eec64667417b```
````

Comment: "Missing source file for SymbolicUtils [d1185830-fcd6-423d-90d6-eec64667417b]
Symbolics [0c5d862f-8b57-4792-8d23-62f2024744c7]". That's peculiar. Looks like the download failed? Try `]build Symbolics` to see if it downloads the second time?

Comment: ] build Symbolics yields: 
```0 dependencies successfully precompiled in 2 seconds (327 already precompiled, 2 skipped during auto due to previous errors)       2 dependencies errored. To see a full report either run `import Pkg; Pkg.precompile()` or load the packages```